# String is not a function error?

Tags: javascript, string

### Background

I am learning JavaScript using Code Academy and am stuck on one of the tasks they have set. The console they provide give no guidance to what line the error in on. The only help it provides is an error message.

### Question

I'm receiving this error message

> TypeError: string is not a function

from this block of JavaScript

```
confirm("Are you ready to play?");
var age = prompt("what is your age?");

if(age > 13){
    console.log("You are allowed to play but we hold no responsiblity");
}else{
    console.log("You can play, crack on");
}

console.log("You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this lyric 'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'");

console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'"); 
var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?");

if (userAnswer === "yes"){
    console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
}else{
    console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");
}

var feedback = prompt("Rate this game out of 10 bitch!");

if (feedback > 7){
    console.log("Thank you! We should race at the next concert!");
}else{

      console.log("Ill keep practicing coding and racing.");
}
```

Any idea where this error is coming from would be great help.

### EDIT

After making changes suggested by various users, code is still marked as incorrect and error message still persists.

More info on when script exits

script exits after prompt:

> "what is your age"?

Comment: `age > 13` ??? age is a string. you might want to do this instead `+age>13`

Comment: This didn't make any difference, thanks though.

Comment: Run this in console. `"11">012`. don't think : this will never happen. not to mention if you'll ever do `"11"+1`( adding a year) : you will get `"111"`

Comment: I dont understand what you mean or want me to do.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: this is because `012` is `10`. `11 > 012` returns true as well. Comparing a string with a number works as expected as long as the string can be converted to a number.

Comment: @SalmanA I'm saying. being a good programmer should handle all cases. tomorrow he want to add a year to `age`. he will probably do `age+1`. it will yield wrong result. why digging holes to yourself ? the fact that 012  is octaled calculated is not relates. it relates to the strict value (which is here - a string) of a given value

Comment: @DanCundy if your confirm should return integer - then _treat it as an integer_. In other words : `if(parseInt(age,10) > 13){...` or `if(+age > 13){`

Comment: @RoyiNamir: in this case urge the user to validate the user input instead of treating garbage as integer.

Comment: my confirm is intended to do nothing, thus is does nothing and stores nothing...

Comment: I am well aware that in the script i have created i have no validation for any input, i am going through steps in a online "school/class". Validation in this lesson is beyond its scope and merely an overkill and time wasted.

Comment: @DanCundy: `console.log` could still be the string resulting from previous run of your script. Try closing and re-opening the console/refresh the page/etc.

Comment: @SalmanA, Thats strange. Did as you said and its now working. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines:

```
console.log = "You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!";
console.log = "Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'";
```

... change `console.log` (which is a function) to a string. While this is a mistake, it does not produce any error, not immediately at least. The error is raised on the lines that say:

```
console.log("Thank you! We should race at the next concert!");
console.log("Ill keep practicing coding and racing.");
```

You are trying to invoke a string as a function, much like:

```
"aaa"();
```

This throws the error "string is not a function". Only functions, function variables, function expressions (etc) can be invoked using `()`.

Answer (score 7):

typo,

```
 console.log="You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!";
```

put brackets.

```
console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
    confirm("Are you ready to play?");
    var age = prompt("what is your age?");

```
if(age > 13){
    console.log("You are allowed to play but we hold no responsiblity");
}else{
    console.log("you can play, crack on");
}

console.log("You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this lyric 'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'");

console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'"); 
var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?");

if (userAnswer === "yes"){
    console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
}else{
    console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");
}

var feedback = prompt("Rate this game out of 10 bitch!");
if (feedback == 7){
    console.log("Thank you! We should race at the next concert!");
}
else{
  console.log("Else Thank you! We should race at the next concert!");
}
```